# Fade In & Out with animating position - better way to write this?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a better way to write the following?

```
$(function(){      
     $('.start-here-notice').fadeIn(1000).animate({"left":"-155px"}, "slow")  
     $('.start-here-notice').animate({"left":"-165px"}, "slow").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);           
});
```

It works fine, but I think there might be a more efficient way to write this. If so, I probably would animate it a couple more times.

Still learning here and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you setup a js fiddle so we know what the animation does?

Comment: jQuery is efficient, but never nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can call as many jQuery methods as you like on an object, by chaining them:

  ```
  $(function(){      
      $('.start-here-notice')
          .fadeIn(1000)
          .animate({"left":"-155px"}, "slow")  
          .animate({"left":"-165px"}, "slow")
          .delay(5000)
          .fadeOut(1000);           
  });
  ```
- Accessing an element by id is slightly faster than accessing it by class. (In this case, the difference is trivial, since you’re only doing it once.)
- If you're going to work with the same element again, you might store the result of `$('.start-here-notice')` in a variable, so that you only have to look it up once. (Again, the performance gains are trivial in this case. You start to see a benefit from storing jQuery objects when you use them many times at once, like dealing with a large number of elements, or frequently, like in an event handler that fires repeatedly.)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that immediately jumps out at me is setting your jquery lookup to a variable.

```
var startHereNotice = $('.start-here-notice');
startHereNotice.fadeIn(1000)...
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$(function(){      
    $('.start-here-notice').fadeIn(1000).animate({"left":"-155px"}, "slow", function(){
        $(this).animate({"left":"-165px"}, "slow").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

… comes to mind. Then again, it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could animate opacity on the same call to animate

```
$('.start-here-notice').animate({"left":"-155px", "opacity":1}, "slow")
$('.start-here-notice').animate({"left":"-155px", "opacity":0}, "slow")
```

But take care, opacity is not fully suported on ie6 and ie7. Use alfa-filter instead

EDIT: Well, the second call, if you want to delay de fadeOut, your implementation is fine. delay() is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's most efficient to define class-based elements in jQuery using the find function, and also include the html element type.

You currently have:

```
   $('.start-here-notice')
```

You should consider doing something like this (assuming .start-here-notice is a DIV)

```
   $('#parent').find('div.start-here-notice')
```

To be clear, if you have a minimal to moderate amount DOM elements on the page and limited JavaScript, you will almost certainly not notice a speed increase.  This is simply the most efficient method.

Comment: Would `$('#parent .start-here-notice')` be equivalent? If so, the performance benefit is due to descending from an id, not using `.find()`.

Comment: It is generally faster (in CSS, too) to *leave out* the tag name. Then, jQuery (or the browser) doesn’t have to filter the results to include only `div`s.

Comment: You're correct about leaving out the tag name, I was wrong on that.  But, using the $(ID CLASS) approach is technically slower than using the $(ID).find(CLASS) approach, since jQuery converts the first into the latter.  It essientially eliminates one function call.

Comment: I was wrong about a combined selector being faster, but that's not because of jQuery — it just gives the selector to `querySelectorAll` in newer browsers. It turns out that, in WebKit (which browser are you using?), `querySelectorAll` is highly optimized for plain ids, but falls back to a slower search for other selectors. This could be improved majorly inside WebKit. [Here's a jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/qsa-descend-vs-map/3).